# Crystal Report runtime está travando

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, runtime

Olá estou tentando corrigir um erro em minha aplicação, utilizei o FUSLOGVW.exe para saber quais erram as dlls que estavam faltando. Ele está me devolvendo essa msg: Mas a dll msvcm80.dll mão faz parte do meu projeto, como posso fazer para inclui-la? Veja a msg erro erro:

> ***** Entrada de Log do Fichário de Assembly  (30/06/2015 @ 08:12:41) ***
>
> A operação falhou. Resultado da associação: hr = 0x80131040. Nenhuma
>   descrição disponível.
>
> Gerenciador de assemblies carregado de: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Executando sob
>   executável  C:\Sistema\SisEco.exe
>   --- Segue um log detalhado de erros.
>
> === Informações sobre estado pré-associação === LOG: DisplayName = msvcm80, Version=8.0.50727.4940, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Sistema/ LOG: PrivatePath inicial = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base
>   = NULL LOG: Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName = SisEco.exe Chamando assembly: (Unknown).
>   === LOG: esta associação começa no contexto de carregamento default. LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de aplicativo:
>   C:\Sistema\SisEco.exe.Config LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de
>   host:  LOG: usando arquivo de configuração da máquina de
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: referência pós-política: msvcm80, Version=8.0.50727.4940,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a LOG: a pesquisa de
>   GAC não foi bem-sucedida. LOG: tentando download de nova URL
>   file:///C:/Sistema/msvcm80.DLL. LOG: o download do assembly foi
>   bem-sucedido. Tentando configuração do arquivo: C:\Sistema\msvcm80.dll
>   LOG: entrando na fase de configuração executada a partir da origem.
>   LOG: o nome do assembly é: msvcm80, Version=8.0.50727.4927,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a AVI: a comparação de
>   nome de assembly resultou na incompatibilidade: Revision Number ERR: a
>   referência do assembly não correspondeu à definição de assembly
>   localizada. ERR: falha na fase de configuração executada a partir da
>   origem com hr = 0x80131040. ERR: falha ao concluir configuração do
>   assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing encerrado.
>
> *** Entrada de Log do Fichário de Assembly  (30/06/2015 @ 08:12:41) ***
>
> A operação falhou. Resultado da associação: hr = 0x80131040. Nenhuma
>   descrição disponível.
>
> Gerenciador de assemblies carregado de: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Executando sob
>   executável  C:\Sistema\SisEco.exe
>   --- Segue um log detalhado de erros.
>
> === Informações sobre estado pré-associação === LOG: DisplayName = msvcm80, Version=8.0.50727.4940, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Sistema/ LOG: PrivatePath inicial = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base
>   = NULL LOG: Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName = SisEco.exe Chamando assembly: (Unknown).
>   === LOG: esta associação começa no contexto de carregamento default. LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de aplicativo:
>   C:\Sistema\SisEco.exe.Config LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de
>   host:  LOG: usando arquivo de configuração da máquina de
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: referência pós-política: msvcm80, Version=8.0.50727.4940,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a LOG: a pesquisa de
>   GAC não foi bem-sucedida. LOG: tentando download de nova URL
>   file:///C:/Sistema/msvcm80.DLL. LOG: o download do assembly foi
>   bem-sucedido. Tentando configuração do arquivo: C:\Sistema\msvcm80.dll
>   LOG: entrando na fase de configuração executada a partir da origem.
>   LOG: o nome do assembly é: msvcm80, Version=8.0.50727.4927,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a AVI: a comparação de
>   nome de assembly resultou na incompatibilidade: Revision Number ERR: a
>   referência do assembly não correspondeu à definição de assembly
>   localizada. ERR: falha na fase de configuração executada a partir da
>   origem com hr = 0x80131040. ERR: falha ao concluir configuração do
>   assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing encerrado**

Answer (score 0):

Depois de quebra a cabeça e quase ficar louco,
descobri o que ocasionou o erro.

A fonte de dados do ODBC estava configurada só para "Fonte de dados de usuário".

Foi só eu trocar para a "Fonte de dados de sistema" que esta tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Então marque sua reposta como aceita